# Memory leak in Fortran linked list using pointers

Tags: pointers, memory-leaks, linked-list, fortran

I'm trying to create a linked list structure in Fortran for a fixed point iteration between particles in a computational zone. Particles are iteratively traced through a computational zone, their properties from each step are stored; and they interact with the particle properties from the previous iteration.

For this problem I have two linked lists, one which holds the particle properties from the previous iteration (`list_use`, with which the particles currently being traced through the domain interact) and another list which accumulates the properties of the particles as they are traced through the computational zone. After one iteration (i.e. after all particles have been traced through the domain once), I want to discard `list_use` (interactions with this data have already been computed), copy `list_buildup` into `list_use` and then discard `list_buildup`, so that it can be repopulated with the next data from the iteration.

I appear to have a memory leak when copying and discarding the lists. Here's a reduced bit of code which replicates the memory leak. As far as I can tell, the leak occurs in `updateASR`. I would expect the process memory before this subroutine to be equal to the memory after it, but using the diagnostics on VisualStudio, it shows the memory increasing every time that `updateASR` is called, eventually leading to the program terminating (with an access violation error). [Here's an image showing the VS process memory diagnostic.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IzfF.png) I guess that `destroyASREntries` is somehow not doing what I actually want it to do?

I'm not very experienced with pointers in Fortran and therefore a bit stuck, so any help would be really appreciated!

```
module linked_list

!---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
! Type containing the data for an ASR entry, used to compute interactions between rays.
type ASR_entry
    real                :: intensity    !<- The intensity of the ASR entry
    real                :: ang_freq     !<- Angular frequency
    real,dimension(3)   :: wavevector   !<- Wavevector (x,y,z): Cartesian.
end type ASR_entry

!---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
! A node type in the linked list for the ASR.
type ASR_Node
    type(ASR_Node),pointer  :: next => null()
    type(ASR_Node),pointer  :: prev => null()
    type(ASR_entry)         :: node_entry
end type ASR_Node

!---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
! For interaction, each cell contains one of these ASR linked lists, which itself contains the nodes, which contain the entry.
type ASR_cell_ll
    type(ASR_Node),pointer  :: head =>  null()  !<- first%next points to first node
    type(ASR_Node),pointer  :: last =>  null()  !<- last%prev points to last node
    integer(kind=4)         :: size = 0         !<- Number of ASR entries in the linked list
end type ASR_cell_ll

contains
!---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
! Create the ASR linked list in every cell.
subroutine createASRcell(list)
    implicit none
    type(ASR_cell_ll), pointer :: list
    
    if(associated(list)) call Abort("Must pass null pointer of type 'ASR_cell_ll' to createASRcell.")
    
    !- Allocate memory - is this necessary??
    allocate(list)
    allocate(list%head,list%last)
    list%head%next  => list%last    !<- If list is empty, then the first entry points to the last entry which is null
    list%last%prev  => list%head
    list%size       = 0
    
end subroutine createASRcell

!---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
! Delete all ASR entries
subroutine destroyASREntries(list)
    implicit none
    type(ASR_cell_ll), pointer  :: list
    type(ASR_Node), pointer     :: dCurrent=>null(), dNext=>null()
    
    if (.not. associated(list)) return
    allocate(dCurrent,dNext)
    
    dCurrent    => list%head
    dNext       => dCurrent%next
    
    !- Deallocate all data nodes in list
    do
        nullify(dCurrent%prev)  !- Remove dangling pointers from the list structure.
        deallocate(dCurrent)
        if (.not. associated(dNext)) exit
        dCurrent    => dNext
        dNext       => dCurrent%next
    end do
    
    nullify(dCurrent,dNext) !- Remove dangling pointers
    
    list%size=0
    deallocate(list)
    
end subroutine destroyASREntries

!---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
!- This subroutine removes the old entries in list_use, copies the list_buildup entries into list_use, then empties list_buildip for the next iteration.
subroutine updateASR(list_use, list_buildup)
    implicit none
    type(ASR_cell_ll),pointer   :: list_use, list_buildup
    
    !First destroy all entries from the previous ASR iteration, before recreating the list.
    call destroyASREntries(list_use)
    call createASRcell(list_use)
    
    !Then make the use list the previous iterations buildup list.
    list_use => list_buildup
    
    !The stop buildup from pointing to the use list's new entries, before recreating buildup as blank.
    nullify(list_buildup)
    call createASRcell(list_buildup)
    
end subroutine updateASR

end module linked_list

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

module definitions
    implicit none
    integer :: nx,ny,nz,nbeams  !Dimensions of the linked list domain.
    integer :: ix,iy,iz,ibeam   !Loop variables
    
end module definitions

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

program main
    use definitions
    use linked_list
    implicit none
    type(asr_cell_ll),pointer   :: list_use,list_buildup    !<-The temporary and used linked list.
    integer :: i
    
    call createASRcell(list_buildup)
    call createASRcell(list_use)
    
    do i=1,1000000000
        call updateASR(list_use,list_buildup)
    enddo
    
end program main
```

I compiled the above with ifort.

Comment: Is there a particular reason for you to prefer pointers over allocatables?

Comment: I don't know before each iteration how many entries the list will have so I thought a linked list made the most sense.

Comment: Rather than asking whether you needed a linked list instead of an array, I meant whether you have a reason to prefer implementing the linked list using pointer components instead of allocatable (scalar) components. (It's fine to say "yes, I want to use pointers" - preferably with a "because ...", but pointers and memory leaks are much better friends than allocatables and memory leaks.)

Comment: I think compiler compatibility might be a valid reason.

Comment: Ah I see. So for my problem, I have a full domain with a size of order 100*100*100 (so millions of zones) and I need one of these linked lists in each of those cells, each with an arbitrary number of entries (probably on the order of 100 ->1000). As I understand (correct me if I'm wrong please!) using allocatables would require contiguous memory, which I suppose would be unfeasible for this size of problem? Again, not very familiar with pointers generally so please correct me if I'm misunderstanding!

Comment: Hi @VladimirFГероямслава, could you elaborate please?

Comment: You can use allocatables the same way as pointers. There is actually very little difference. If you wanted to use arrays then yes, allocatable arrays are contiguous. But so are arrays allocatated through pointers.

Comment: Ah, @VladimirFГероямслава, unfortunately I am stuck to fortran90 (wish that I could out of the dark ages, but not my choice unfortunately), so I can't use allocatable scalars here.

Comment: There are questions about linked lists using allocatables you can read for some background, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69544624/3157076). As Vladimir says, there's not too much difference, in memory layout, but potentially a big difference in which compilers support them (and which compilers support them without bugs that may hurt you). Linked lists with allocatables don't leak.

Comment: If you're stuck with Fortran 90, then I'm afraid you've an awful lot of rewriting of the code you have ahead of you. Even what you show here is not valid F90.

Comment: Fortran 90 is dead. And inconsistent. Compilers consider Fortran 95 as the reasonable base to support. You can try `gfortran -std=f95` and see the locationswhere the compiler complains.

Comment: @francescalus, Sorry, my mistake. I think we are using 95 not f90!

Comment: When compiling in gfortran in Linux I do not get a memory leak, but I am getting  "Must pass null pointer of type 'ASR_cell_ll' to createASRcell." When I enable address sanitizations, the program runs indefinitely. Valgrind complains that the check `if(associated(list))` at line 34 depends on an uninitialized value.

Comment: To stop that, nullify the pointers in the program. Then you can follow he leaks using 1. valgrind or 2. `-fsanize=leak` in gfortran.

Comment: Ah, I am using ifort, which I think is less picky than gfortran or cray when it comes to declaring pointers as null when initialised, so mine ran fine. I'll try getting valgrind to see if I get any errors when using ifort!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @veryreverie for their answer which helped solve the leak and clear up my misunderstanding. The issue was due to allocating pointers before then repointing them to new memory in `createASRcell` and `destroyASREntries`. [Here is the diagnotic with the new code showing no memory leak.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8eF0.png) Here is the modified, working code without memory leaks in case anyone is interested:

```
module linked_list

!---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
! Type containing the data for an ASR entry, used to compute interactions between rays.
type ASR_entry
    real                :: intensity    !<- The intensity of the ASR entry
    real                :: ang_freq     !<- Angular frequency
    real,dimension(3)   :: wavevector   !<- Wavevector (x,y,z): Cartesian.
end type ASR_entry

!---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
! A node type in the linked list for the ASR.
type ASR_Node
    type(ASR_Node),pointer  :: next => null()
    type(ASR_Node),pointer  :: prev => null()
    type(ASR_entry)         :: node_entry
end type ASR_Node

!---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
! For interaction, each cell contains one of these ASR linked lists, which itself contains the nodes, which contain the entry.
type ASR_cell_ll
    type(ASR_Node),pointer  :: head =>  null()  !<- first%next points to first node
    type(ASR_Node),pointer  :: last =>  null()  !<- last%prev points to last node
    integer(kind=4)         :: size = 0         !<- Number of ASR entries in the linked list
end type ASR_cell_ll

contains
!---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
! Create the ASR linked list in every cell.
subroutine createASRcell(list)
    implicit none
    type(ASR_cell_ll), pointer :: list
    
    if(associated(list)) call Abort("Must pass null pointer of type 'ASR_cell_ll' to createASRcell.")
    
    allocate(list)
    allocate(list%head,list%last)
    
    list%head%next  => list%last    !<- If list is empty, then the first entry points to the last entry which is null
    list%last%prev  => list%head
    list%size       = 0
    
end subroutine createASRcell

!---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
! Delete all ASR entries
subroutine destroyASREntries(list)
    implicit none
    type(ASR_cell_ll), pointer  :: list
    type(ASR_Node), pointer     :: dCurrent=>null(), dNext=>null()
    
    if (.not. associated(list)) return
    
    dCurrent    => list%head
    
    !- Deallocate all data nodes in list
    do while(associated(dCurrent))
        dNext => dCurrent%next
        nullify(dCurrent%prev)  !- Remove dangling pointers from the list structure.
        nullify(dCurrent%next)  !- Remove dangling pointers from the list structure.
        deallocate(dCurrent)
        dCurrent    => dNext
    end do
    
    ! - Deallocate the list itself
    deallocate(list)
    
end subroutine destroyASREntries

!---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
!- This subroutine removes the old entries in list_use, copies the list_buildup entries into list_use, then empties list_buildip for the next iteration.
subroutine updateASR(list_use, list_buildup)
    implicit none
    type(ASR_cell_ll),pointer   :: list_use, list_buildup
    
    call destroyASREntries(list_use)    !First destroy all entries from the previous ASR iteration  
    list_use => list_buildup            !Then make the use list the previous iterations buildup list.
    nullify(list_buildup)               !The stop buildup from pointing to the use list's new entries
    
end subroutine updateASR

end module linked_list

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

module definitions
    implicit none
    integer :: nx,ny,nz,nbeams  !Dimensions of the linked list domain.
    integer :: ix,iy,iz,ibeam   !Loop variables
    
end module definitions

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

program main
    use definitions
    use linked_list
    implicit none
    type(asr_cell_ll),pointer   :: list_use=>null(),list_buildup=>null()    !<-The temporary and used linked list.
    integer :: i
    
    call createASRcell(list_buildup)
    call createASRcell(list_use)
    
    do i=1,1000000000
        call updateASR(list_use,list_buildup)
    enddo
    
end program main
```

Comment: Out of interest, why are you allocating memory in `createASRcell`?

Comment: If I don't allocate the list in that subroutine, I get an error when trying to point list%head to something in `destroy...`

Comment: Looks like I made a mistake copying my code to my answer. I've fixed that now. You should be able to `createASRcell` without allocating any `ASR_Node`s at all.

Answer (score 2):

First, let's look at `createASRcell`. It returns a `ASR_cell_ll` with `size=0`. So why are you allocating memory? You should only allocate a node when you want a node. I think `createASRcell` should be

```
subroutine createASRcell(list)
  type(ASR_cell_ll), pointer :: list
      
  if(associated(list)) call Abort("Must pass null pointer of type 'ASR_cell_ll' to createASRcell.")

  list%head => null()
  list%last => null()
  list%size = 0      
end subroutine
```

Second, let's look at `destroyASREntries`. The lines

```
allocate(dCurrent,dNext)
  
dCurrent => list%head
dNext => dCurrent%next
```

are creating two nodes, at `dCurrent` and `dNext`, and then immediately losing track of these nodes to point `dCurrent` and `dNext` at new targets. This will leak the memory you just allocated. The `allocate` statement just shouldn't be there. There's also quite a lot of excess deallocation going on. Simplifying the subroutine, we get

```
subroutine destroyASREntries(list)
  type(ASR_cell_ll), pointer :: list

  type(ASR_Node), pointer :: dCurrent, dNext
  
  if (.not. associated(list)) return

  dCurrent => list%head
  
  !- Deallocate all data nodes in list
  do while(associated(dCurrent))
    dNext => dCurrent%next
    nullify(dCurrent%prev)
    nullify(dCurrent%next)
    deallocate(dCurrent)
    dCurrent => dNext
  end do

  ! - Deallocate the list itself
  deallocate(list)
end subroutine destroyASREntries
```

Finally, let's look at `updateASR`. I don't quite understand what you're trying to do here, but the subroutine is going to cause problems. The lines

```
call destroyASREntries(list_use)
call createASRcell(list_use)
list_use => list_buildup
```

will clean up the old `ASR_cell_ll` pointed to by `list_use`, create a new empty `ASR_cell_ll`, again pointed to by `list_use`, and then immediately lose track of this new list by pointing `list_use` at `list_buildup`. This will leak all the memory of the newly created `ASR_cell_ll`.

Comment: This was really helpful and worked great with a tiny modification! I just needed to allocate the `list` and `list%head`, `list%last` in the modified `createASRcell`. I had written the original without a full understanding of when to allocate pointers and what exactly the function was doing but your answer corrected my understanding so thanks very much indeed!